# CSS border-style: wave

Tags: css, border

I came across this document on w3.org:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/borderstyles.png that shows a border-style: wave property. Eager to try I tested it out in Firefox and in Chrome, but alas. Was there any point at which this property setting was fully supported? For which browsers?

Comment: Based on [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/) it seems you can do it with an image.  See Example 27.

Comment: Yes. On only one day, 7 November 2002.

Comment: @DavidStarkey thanks for the hint, but Example 27 seems to be an example of a border-image, not a standard border-style, right?

Comment: Example 27 in the CSS3 Background specification is an advanced example of what you can do with background images.

Comment: You're pointing to a working draft which is more than 10 years old. The final recommendation doesn't include this : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/

Comment: @j08691: Not even then.

Comment: @BoltClock - was kidding

Comment: That page also has the wave border removed from the image.  I'm not sure how that example works as I've never had the desire for such borders, [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ph4kC/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There is no support for the `border-style:wave` property (along with the `dot-dash` and `dot-dot-dash` properties) in any browser.

If you wanted a wavey border, a solution could be to utilise the [**`border-image`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) property using an image of a wavey border of your choice. Be sure to check out `@David Starkey`'s [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ph4kC/) for a nice example of that.

One thing to note, however, is that the `border-image` property isn't supported in any versions of IE. A good workaround for getting IE6-IE9 to support `border-image` is to use [**CSS3Pie**](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/).

Comment: You may also think of providing alternative solutions.  How can a wavy border be achieved?

Comment: @DavidStarkey You already answered that part with your border-image example

Comment: Yes, that was a comment.  If you want to make an answer, it should be as complete as possible.